# Multiple range sliders

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have multiple html5 range sliders on my page, this was working for one however I can't make this work for seperate sliders. They should have no relation, so the user can select a score on each different question.

I know the jQuery code should target the slider, however I cannot get this to work. We are going to be using around 20 of these sliders, so need this to be dynamic really.

```js
var sheet = document.createElement('style'),
  $rangeInput = $('.range input'),
  prefs = ['webkit-slider-runnable-track', 'moz-range-track', 'ms-track'];

document.body.appendChild(sheet);

var getTrackStyle = function(el) {
  var curVal = el.value,
    val = (curVal - 1) * 25,
    style = '';

  // Set active label
  $('.range-labels li').removeClass('active selected');

  var curLabel = $('.range-labels').find('li:nth-child(' + curVal + ')');
  curLabel.addClass('active selected');
  curLabel.prevAll().addClass('selected');
  //curLabel.addClass('halfselect'); 
  
  // Change background gradient
  for (var i = 0; i < prefs.length; i++) {
    style += '.range {background: linear-gradient(to right, #a50e2d 0%, #a50e2d ' + val + '%, #fff ' + val + '%, #fff 100%)}';
    style += '.range input::-' + prefs[i] + '{background: linear-gradient(to right, #a50e2d 0%, #a50e2d ' + val + '%, #b2b2b2 ' + val + '%, #b2b2b2 100%)}';
  }

  return style;
}

$rangeInput.on('input', function() {
  sheet.textContent = getTrackStyle(this);
});

// Change input value on label click
$('.range-labels li').on('click', function() {
  var index = $(this).index();
  $rangeInput.val(index + 1).trigger('input');
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 100px;
}

.range {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
}

.range input {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  height: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.range input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: -16px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #a50e2d;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0 !important;
}


/*
      .range input::-moz-range-thumb {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        margin: -8px 0  0;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: #a50e2d;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: 0 !important;
      }
      .range input::-ms-thumb {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        margin: -8px 0  0;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: #a50e2d;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: 0 !important;
      }
      */

.range input::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #272725;
}

.range input::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #272725;
}

.range input::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #272725;
}

.range input:focus {
  background: none;
  outline: none;
}

.range input::-ms-track {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  color: transparent;
}

.range-labels {
  margin: 18px -11% 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.range-labels li {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: #272725;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  flex: 1;
}

.range-labels li::before,
.halfselect::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: -37px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: "";
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #272725;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.range-labels .active {
  color: #a50e2d;
}

.range-labels .selected::before,
.range-labels .active::before {
  background: #a50e2d;
}

.range-labels .active.selected::before {
  display: none;
}

.halfselect {}

.halfselect:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -23px;
  right: auto;
  left: 0;
  content: "";
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  height: 5px;
  background: #a50e2d;
  z-index: 9999;
}

span.question {
  color: #272725 !important;
  padding: 5px 0;
  display: block;
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
}

span.inp-value {
  position: absolute;
  top: -60px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  color: #272725;
}
```

```html
<div class="questions">
  <div class="range">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="5" steps="1" value="1">
  </div>
  <ul class="range-labels" id="working-with-people-question1">
    <li id="1" class="active selected"><span class="inp-value">1</span><span class="question">Shows little interest in or understanding of others</span></li>
    <li id="2"><span class="inp-value">2</span></li>
    <li id="3"><span class="inp-value">3</span></li>
    <li id="4"><span class="inp-value">4</span></li>
    <li id="5"><span class="inp-value">5</span><span class="question">Demonstrate an interest in and understanding of others</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="questions" style="padding-top: 100px">
  <div class="range">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="5" steps="1" value="1">
  </div>
  <ul class="range-labels" id="working-with-people-question1">
    <li id="1" class="active selected"><span class="inp-value">1</span><span class="question">Question 2</span></li>
    <li id="2"><span class="inp-value">2</span></li>
    <li id="3"><span class="inp-value">3</span></li>
    <li id="4"><span class="inp-value">4</span></li>
    <li id="5"><span class="inp-value">5</span><span class="question">Question 2</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Codepen here - https://codepen.io/scottYg55/pen/BazGamz

Comment: Can anyone help?

Comment: If you want it to work for each range individually, you will need any selectors inside `getTrackStyle` to be relative to the passed in element. E.g. `$('.range-labels li')` would need to be something like `$(el).closest('.questions').find('.range-labels li')`

Comment: Could you please provide a solutions @DBS?

Comment: ok i see im getting closer, how will i do this for the style part?

Comment: So now how do I target this part -   for (var i = 0; i < prefs.length; i++) {
    style += '.range {background: linear-gradient(to right, #a50e2d 0%, #a50e2d ' + val + '%, #fff ' + val + '%, #fff 100%)}';
    style += '.range input::-' + prefs[i] + '{background: linear-gradient(to right, #a50e2d 0%, #a50e2d ' + val + '%, #b2b2b2 ' + val + '%, #b2b2b2 100%)}';
  }

Comment: Instead of adding a style to the document, you can use jQuery's `.css()` [method](https://api.jquery.com/css/) to apply your style to just the passed in `el` element.

Comment: How would this work when I need the value for the range width in style?

Comment: I just want to suggest you to take a look at a great, easy and responsive range slider plugin: http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that getTrackStyle(this) is sending all the elements and not just (this). (this) is global and not set to the individual (this) function